# How to assign global variable into another file

Tags: python, pycharm

I have file `foo.py`

```py
PARAMS = None
def cals(x):
    return PARAMS + x
```

I want to import `foo.py` into `bar.py` like below

```py
import foo
foo.PARAMS = 4

print(foo.cals(4))
```

but in pycharm it show `redeclared 'PARAMS' defined above without usage`. what meaning of pycharm showed

Comment: Working Fine.What do you get

Comment: @SmartManoj yes, it is warning, but I don't know why Pycharm show that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808529/redeclared-s-defined-above-without-usage

Comment: It shouldn't show in this case

Answer (score 0):

when you import something, it runs through the file. I think it is saying that when you imported foo.py, the keyword PARAMS was not used. I would just ignore it, or if you have OCD you can change it and see if the warming goes away.